# I am not being able to implement JWT token on a server side spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, model-view-controller, spring-security, jwt, token

I have created a MVC spring boot app, mapping with a mySQL table, configured security to allow admin to access list of students and users are able to access list of subjects. Till this point everything is working fine.

Now i wanna put into play the JWT token. The problem is every video i follow use the JWT with post man and with simple @RestControllers but no MVC.

When i try to access 1 of the lists after starting the server, the custom login page comes to play and i enter details and everything works fine.

But, how do I implement the token? I have created a no MVC endpoint named "/authenticate" which returns me a token and using post man it works fine. But how do i return it in the app when i try to login using custom login page? Im not getting smthng here. Any help is appriciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the endpoint for authenticate using postman:

```
@PostMapping ("/authenticate")
public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {
    try {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword()));

    } catch (BadCredentialsException e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Incorrect UserName or Password!",e);
    }

    UserDetails userDetails =
            customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
    String jwt = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse(jwt));

}
```

Here is my security configuration :
http.
csrf().disable()
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/","/registration/**","/logout","/login","/authenticate").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/helloAdmin").hasRole("Admin")
.antMatchers("/helloUser").hasRole("User")
.antMatchers("/students/**").hasRole("Admin")
.antMatchers("/subjects/**").hasAnyRole("User","Admin")
.anyRequest().authenticated()
.and()
.formLogin()
.loginPage("/login")
.and()
.logout()
.logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout");

```
            http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

            http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```